# Read text file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk, file-access

I'm working on mobile app through XDK intel, How can I read text file from outside the app?

I tried this code, but it's not working!

```js
function readFile (filepath){
var txtFile = "C:\test.txt";
var file = new File(txtFile);
file.open("r"); // open file with read access
var str = "";
while (!file.eof) {
 // read each line of text
 str += file.readln() + "\n";
}
file.close();
alert(str);
     }
```

Comment: You have check the permission form XDK intel ,most of the mobile os dost allow to read the files from inside the memory becz of security reason.

Comment: I already check the permissions, but still not reading

Comment: I dont have SDK intel, becoz when I was working in windows phone project , they wont permit to allow internal phone memory for some security purpose. Pls make read all documents and try it. We waste one week.

Comment: There is no concept of a "C:" on a mobile device, that is a PC thing. Also, as Nicolas points out in one of the answers below, you need to use the Cordova File Plugin to locate any files that are not directly within your app. But even with that, as @nisar points out, you do not have access to most of he filesystem on the device.

Comment: Hi, when I run my similar code in Nodejs and in browser, I am getting error as, File is not defined or two arguments required for File(). How can I run the code in a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You are building a Cordova app (aka PhoneGap app) when you are creating an app for the Intel XDK. So the rules (and solutions) that apply to Cordova also apply to Intel XDK apps. The XDK is simply providing a way to make it easier to apply and use the standard Cordova tools, it is not providing a different runtime environment (other than including the option to replace the Android webview with a Crosswalk webview).

This describes, at a very high level, what Cordova and Cordova plugins do on an Android device > http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html. Similar approaches are taken on iOS and Windows and other platforms supported by Cordova.

As Nicolas stated in his answer, you should use the [Cordova File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). On the doc page for that plugin you'll find two references that are worth reading:

- http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Also, these may be of value:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage
- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html